# Is There a Way to Return a String Concatenation in Python?

Tags: python

I've been using Perl for some time and have gotten used to the syntax:

```
return "$var1$var2";
```

for easily returning a concatenation of two strings in one step. Is there a way to do something similar in Python? I'd love to avoid doing it in two steps, if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple:

```
>>> "a" + "b"
'ab'
>>> "%s%s" % ("a", "b")
'ab'
>>> "{a}{b}".format(a="a", b="b")
'ab'
>>> "{}{}".format("a", "b")
'ab'
>>> "{0}{1}".format("a", "b")
'ab'
>>> "a" "b"
'ab'
>>> "".join(("a", "b"))
'ab'
```

Comment: A minor addition -- adjacent string literals are concatenated at compile time: `>>> "a" "b" => 'ab'`.

Comment: `>>>var1 = "a" >>>var2 = var1 += "b" >>>var 2 #"ab"`

Comment: +1. So much for "There should be only one obvious way to do it".

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how addition is two steps.

```
return var1 + var2
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `+`.

```
def f():
    a = 'aaa'
    b = 'bbb'
    return a + b
```